# How do I create a URL linked to a specific post?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to build a Question & Answeer kind of website, like Stack Overflow but a much simpler one. I'm wondering how am I suppose to be able to generate a URL (a page) for a specific question asked by the user?

Do I store the URL directly into my database? I'm building it with PHP, and MySQL.

Comment: Thank you for the edit Martin, and all the answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need create a unique key on your question table like this.

```
CREATE TABLE questions (
   id integer auto_increment primary key
  ,title varchar(100) not null 
  -- ...
  -- yours table fields
  -- ...
)
```

Or use you id primary key like key to select your question.

I suppose that the url is very similar to the next:

http://www.yourdomain.com/questions.php?q=1002

When you are listing yours questions to make links try this inside of loop php :

```
<a href="http://www.yourdomain.com/questions.php?q=<?=$question_info['id']?>"> 
 <?=$question_info['title']?> 
</a>
```

When you  select your question,  you need get a param of url. For example with $_GET vars like this:

```
<?php 
    $mysqli = new('server','user','pass','bd_name');

    $question_id = $_GET['q'];

    $query="SELECT * FROM questions WHERE id='$question_id'";
    //now you can launch the query to mysql
    $result = $mysqli->query($query);
    //get the rows array
    $question_info = $result->fetch_array();    
    //your implementation
    //.....
?>
```

Also you can use with $_POST vars to add comments to a question using a unique key.

This the easy answer but there is a big problem of security with this method because you need clean the $_GET vars to prevent SQL-Injection , but this not is the question now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to store post identifier in your database and use it to match URL. So your post URLs should include identifier: `http://example.org/posts/<post-identifier-here>`